# Relationship between frame rate and sampling frequency in speech signal processing?

Tags: speech, window-functions, speech-processing

While I was going through the short time processing of speech signals, I got stuck at the relationship between the frame rate and the sampling frequency.

Is there any relationship between them for an audio signal so that the change in sampling frequency will have an effect in the frame rate? If yes, what is mathematical relationship between them for given values of **window length (L), window shift (R), Sampling frequency (Fs) and Frame Rate (FR)?**

Answer (score 1):

The sample rate divided by the frame rate will give you the window shift in samples.  The ratio of the window (length - shift) to the window length will give you an overlap factor.  The sample rate divided by the window length in samples will give you the FFT result bin spacing.